# Aligning a child div centered/bottom in parent

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'd like to align a child `div` inside a parent `div` (`header-image` as background image) centered vertical and horizontally to the bottom.

```
<div id="header-image">
    <div class="row">
        ... Content
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a solution for horizontal centering:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;">
        ... content
    </div>
</div>
```

But no idea how to get the content to the bottom (works only with `position:absolute`)

For better understanding on http://webstopp.de/ you can see a `header-image` and some text in it but the text has to be on bottom of the `header-image` `div`.

Comment: make a jsfiddle to show exactly what you're trying to do. Also, did you consider just using the the CSS 'background' property?

Comment: made a jsfiddle - see http://jsfiddle.net/7CDzq/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#header-image {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[banner img]") no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.row {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom:0;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toddihh/7CDzq/9/)

Comment: Hm, tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/toddihh/7CDzq/ but the content isn't on bottom of the header-image.

Comment: @toddiHH: well, I misunderstood your requirement. Check updated answer

Comment: OK the .row is now at the bottom, but the #header-image moves 50% to the left. I need the .row as an overlay over the #header-image. See on  http://webstopp.de/ as well. Any Idea?

Comment: but in fact of position: absolute, the row can't align centered. Using the left:50%, left:-50% isn't possible in this case, because the header.image moves to the right than. margin: 0 auto is also not working because of the position: absolute. Maybe I put a div class="inner" into the div class="row" (fiddle updated)

Answer (score -4):

Try this for your child div: `margin-top: 99%;`